# When can pairs of states be transformed into other pairs of states via unitary mapping?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, unitarity

The states $|+\rangle, |-\rangle$ can be mapped to $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$ by a simple rotation.

But if I now have other states ($|\psi_0\rangle, |\psi_1\rangle$) which are not orthogonal, does a unitary transformation of these states to two other states ($|\phi_0\rangle, |\phi_1\rangle$) exist?

And how can I find this unitary transformation?

Comment: This article may be of interest for you: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407010

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a unitary that maps $\{|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle\}$ to $\{|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\}$ if and only if
$$
\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle.
$$

Thy "only if" direction is straightforward. Let's assume $U|\psi_i\rangle=|\phi_i\rangle$. Then
$$
\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1|U^\dagger U|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle.
$$

The "if" direction requires a little more care. Let $|\psi^\perp\rangle$ be the component of $|\psi_2\rangle$ that is orthogonal to $|\psi_1\rangle$. Similarly for $|\phi^\perp\rangle$. So, we claim that if we can find a unitary $U$ such that
$$
U|\psi_1\rangle=|\phi_1\rangle,\qquad U|\psi^\perp\rangle=|\phi^\perp\rangle,
$$
then we are done because
$$
U|\psi_2\rangle=U(\cos\theta|\psi_1\rangle+\sin\theta|\psi^\perp\rangle)=(\cos\theta|\phi_1\rangle+\sin\theta|\phi^\perp\rangle)=|\psi_2\rangle
$$
where $\cos\theta=|\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle|=|\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle|$.

Now let $\{|\gamma_i\rangle\}$ be *any* orthonormal basis with $|\gamma_1\rangle=|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\gamma_2\rangle=|\psi^\perp\rangle$ and let $\{|\lambda_i\rangle\}$ be an orthonormal basis with $|\lambda_1\rangle=|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\lambda_2\rangle=|\psi^\perp\rangle$. We can define
$$
U=\sum_i|\lambda_i\rangle\langle \gamma_i|.
$$
This certainly provides the required transformation.

Answer (score 2):

A small rewarding of the argument in [this other answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/21413/55):

1. Given $\{|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle\}$ and $\{|\phi_1\rangle,|\phi_2\rangle\}$ such that $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=\langle\phi_1|\phi_2\rangle$, we can always write
   $$|\psi_2\rangle = \cos\theta |\psi_1\rangle + \sin\theta|\psi_1^\perp\rangle,\\
   |\phi_2\rangle = \cos\theta |\phi_1\rangle + \sin\theta|\phi_1^\perp\rangle,$$
   for some angle $\theta$ given by $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=\cos\theta$, and for some states $|\psi_1^\perp\rangle,|\phi_1^\perp\rangle$. These are defined as
   $$|\psi_1^\perp\rangle\equiv \frac{|\psi_2\rangle-\cos\theta|\psi_1\rangle}{\sin\theta},
   \qquad
   |\phi_1^\perp\rangle\equiv \frac{|\phi_2\rangle-\cos\theta|\phi_1\rangle}{\sin\theta},$$
   and are such that $\langle\psi_1^\perp|\psi_1\rangle=\langle\phi_1^\perp|\phi_1\rangle=0$.
2. Given any pair of states $|\psi\rangle,|\phi\rangle$, you can always find unitary operators $U$ such that $U|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle$. The choice of $U$ is not unique. Let us then assume that $U|\psi_1\rangle=|\phi_1\rangle$. Our goal will be to show that we can find $U$ such that we also have $U|\psi_2\rangle=|\phi_2\rangle$. But given our observation in the first point, this is equivalent to finding $U$ such that $U|\psi_1^\perp\rangle=U|\phi_1^\perp\rangle$.
3. We thus reduced the problem to finding a unitary $U$ which maps $|\psi_1\rangle\mapsto |\phi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_1^\perp\rangle\mapsto |\phi_1^\perp\rangle$. But finding a unitary sending orthogonal states into orthogonal states is trivial to do: for example, we could just define $U$ as $$U = |\phi_1\rangle\!\langle\psi_1| + |\phi_1^\perp\rangle\!\langle\psi_1^\perp|,$$
   and this can be readily seen to be unitary and implement the correct mapping.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it appears you know the two sets of states ahead of time. If so and the $|\psi_0\rangle$ and $|\psi_1\rangle$ are not orthogonal, then a unitary transformation that transforms |$\psi_0\rangle$ to $|\phi_0\rangle$ is not guaranteed to transform |$\psi_1\rangle$ to $|\phi_1\rangle$. There could be one, in special cases, but not always.

However, if both sets are orthogonal, then I expect to have a unitary transformation that could do that every time.

Edit: If they are not orthogonal, but the inner products of both the sets are the same i.e. if $\langle \psi_0 | \psi_1 \rangle$ =  $\langle \phi_0 
 | \phi_1 \rangle$ and if $U$ exists where $\phi_0 = U |\psi_0 \rangle$, then it follows $\phi_1 = U |\psi_1 \rangle$.

This is because $\langle \phi_0 | \phi_1 \rangle$ = $\langle  \psi_0 | U^{\dagger}  U |\psi_1 \rangle$ , and since $U^{\dagger}  U = I$ .

And $U = \sum_{j} |\phi_j \rangle \langle \psi_j |$

Ref: [Qiskit Universality](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-gates/proving-universality.html)

Comment: Yes, such a mapping cannot always exist. If the inner products are different certainly not. But is it always possible to find a mapping when the inner products are the same? And if so, how?

Comment: @JohnyDow , I have edited the answer

Comment: Thanks! But looking at the source you provided the defined $U$ works only if the states are an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I believe, the source says it works for orthonormal basis, because the inner products are equal implicitly.

Comment: Do you know how to find $U$ if the states are not orthogonal? =)

Comment: The source also says "Another consequence of unitarity is that it preserves the inner product between two arbitrary states". So it is applicable to non-orthonormal sets as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130246/discussion-between-johny-dow-and-codester).